# Possible to get last 2, or even 3 URLS back from the user? similar to document.referrer

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

So, I am basically just trying to grab the previous URL of my new user (to discover how they got there), but it's a little more complicated because I have a redirect, etc. So, the below actually pulls in the redirect.. so my question: In a similar method as below, is there a way to get 2, or even 3 URLs back?

```
  var referrer = document.referrer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

If you want to record that information, you'll need to store it yourself when they hit your first redirect. If you want history before that, you're out of luck; that's private.

Comment: I agree. There's no way to pull redirects from other people's websites, when they link over to yours. So you'll only be able to go 1 referrer hop back, like ? > ? > ? > lastWebsite > myWebsite. Then you can track anywhere that users want to go in your website. You'll be able to track where they exit at, but not beyond that.